# libxml2 writer differences

Tags: c, libxml2

The bulk of the examples I can find for `libxml2` are all about loading/parsing XML files. But I'm only interested in writing them; the code will never have to parse any files. There is an example [using different writers](http://xmlsoft.org/examples/testWriter.c), where it shows how to use the `file`, `memory`, `DOM` and `tree` models.

Looking through the code, I don't see any significant differences between them when it comes to writing. How does one decide which is better to use? (In other words, in what cases is one better than the others?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differences between the 4 functions you specify are minimal, it's all about where the contents go.  As Alex mentioned, if memory is a concern, using `xmlNewTextWriterFilename` has the advantage of not needing to hold the result in memory.

The xmlWriter API, to which all the methods you mentioned belong, is one of the APIs offered.  The other of note is the [tree API](http://xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html#Tree).  xmlWriter is more like calling write() to print to a file, and the tree is more like building nested structs in memory.

The tree-based versions can be good if your data is constructed in a non-linear fasion, going back and adding/changing things based on later information, etc.  This would require some workarounds/caching with the streaming xmlWriter interface, as you can't change things once they've been output.  The in-memory tree, however, can be fully tweaked until the instant it's serialized.

The tree API has the downside of the fact it has to keep the entire thing im memory; the rule of thumb is the memory requirements for a parsed tree is rougly 4x the size of serialized xml file.

My decision is usually dependent on whether I expect to create large documents.  If not, I use the if the tree api, as the flexibility will be there if I want it.  If I know efficiency will be a concern or I'll be working with large stuff, the streaming xmlWriter is the way to go.

tree API examples can be found here: http://xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html#Tree

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a device with limited memory, you probably don't want to use DOM or memory-based approaches. In that case, you probably want to write out the file as you iterate through the data structure you want to write to XML.